# AWS::Cognito::UserPoolUICustomizationAttachment

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, devops, amazon-cognito

I want to include a logo file in AWS::Cognito::UserPoolUICustomizationAttachment template how can I do that?

1. I tried creating an image URL ImageFile: URL of the image but it is not working
2. I tried converting the Image URL into BASE64 ImageFile:  Base64-encoded binary data object but it is not working

I am expecting that I need to upload my logo file for AWS::Cognito::UserPoolUICustomizationAttachment by using YAML template